# Como pegar o elemento filho

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou querendo pegar o valor do plano, ao clicar no button.

## html

```
 <div class="price-button">
    <input type='hidden' name='plano' value='Plano Padrão' />
    <button type="button" class="sel-plan" title="Selecionar">Selecionar Plano</button>
 </div>
```

## jquery

```
$('.sel-plan').click(function(){
    var elementopai = $(this).parent().attr('class');
});
```

Consegui pegar a div pai do button, mas como eu pego o valor do plano?

Comment: Na verdade vc quer pegar o irmão? no Caso o valor do input "Plano Padrão"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você quer selecionar o `input name='plano'` irmão do `button`, faça algo similar a isso:

```js
 
$('.sel-plan').click(function() {
  // volta para selecionar o elemento pai
  var $elementoPai = $(this).parent();
  // procura dentro do elemento pai o elemento [name="plano"]
  var $elemento = $elementoPai.find('[name="plano"]');

  // se desejar obter o valor do input [name="plano"], que parece ser sua real situação
  var valorPlano = $elemento.val();
  alert("Valor do plano: " + valorPlano);

  // Ou pode, inserir um valor no elemento
  $elemento.val("Oi!");
  // torna o elemento visível
  $elemento.attr("type", "input");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-button">
  <input type='hidden' name='plano' value='Plano Padrão' />
  <button type="button" class="sel-plan" title="Selecionar">Selecionar Plano</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu funcionou..@Fernando

Comment: @user12046, fico feliz por ter ajudado, se as respostas sanaram suas duvidas completamente, em relação a pergunta. Por favor marque a resposta que melhor lhe ajudou como resposta, e também pode dar votos positivos, nas que lhe ajudaram. Se ainda restam duvidas edite a pergunta com as mesmas.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode pegar o valor do plano direto, sem ter que pegar o elemento pai > filho.

```
 $('.sel-plan').click(function(){
    var valorDoPlano = $("[name='plano']").val();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Tem várias maneiras para chegar no resultado:

```
var elementopai = $(this).next().attr('class'); // Busca o próximo irmão
var elementopai = $(this).prev().attr('class'); // Busca o irmão anterior.
```

No seu caso deve usar o `prev()`, pois o elemento 'plano' está antes do botão. Também pode usar a função `siblings()` que retorna todos os irmãos do elemento.